# Extract values from command output to a JSON

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ibm-cloud

I am extracting values from a cloud foundry command. It has to be done via the shell. Here is how the file looks like:

```
User-Provided:
end: 123.12.12.12
text_pass: 980
KEY: 000

Running Environment Variable Groups:
BLUEMIX_REGION: ibm:yp:us-north

Staging Environment Variable Groups:
BLUEMIX_REGION: ibm:yp:us-south
```

I want to extract everything from end to KEY and please note that user-provided will always be the start but the end can be any value. But there will always be a new line.

How do I extract between "User-Provided to new line" and put in a JSON file which I will later use to parse?

So far I'm able to do this:

> `cf env space | awk -F 'end:' '{print $2}'`

this gives me the value of end but not the whole object.

Expected output:

```
{
"end": "123.12.12.12"
"text_pass": "980"
"KEY": "000"
}
```

Comment: Please add the expected output as well for clarity.

Comment: If you do a lot of command line parsing of json data, I recommend taking a look at [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cf env space | awk '/User-Provided/{a = 1; next}/^$/{a = 0} a'

end: 123.12.12.12
text_pass: 980
KEY: 000
```

When pattern `User-Provided` is encountered set a variable `a` and when a blank line is encountered, unset this variable `a`. Now, the lines will be printed out for only the cases when `a` is set.

Edited answer:

```
cf env space |  awk -F" *: *" '/User-Provided/{a=1;print"{";next}/^$/{a=0} END{print "\n}"} a{if(c)printf(","); printf("%s", "\n\""$1"\" : \""$NF"\""); c=1}'
```

This will give the output:

```
{

"end" : "123.12.12.12",
"text_pass" : "980",
"KEY" : "000"
}
```

Latest edit:

```
cf env space | awk '/User-Provided/{a=1;print"{";next}/^$/{a=0} END{print "\n}"} a{if(c)printf(","); sub(/:$/,"",$1); printf("%s", "\n\""$1"\" : \""$NF"\""); c=1}'
```

Comment: how do I put in a JSON format though with quotes as shown in expected output? its okay if its piped to a file

Comment: I mean when I use the above command, I get the json printed without commas between the key-value pairs. I added commas now, although the last key-value pair shouldnt have a comma so it makes the json invalid

Comment: comma for example {"abc": "pqr", "abc1": "pqr1"}

Comment: there should be a comma after "123.12.12.12", "980" but not "000" as its the last element

Comment: thanks a ton, works great. I'll accept the answer. Quick question: if my values are "980:210" but thats the value of key "text_pass", currently its not considering that? same thing if there are url's. i.e. my input can have values "980:780" but it should still consider as 1 value or a URL then also.

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk '/^end:/,/^KEY:/' file
end: 123.12.12.12
text_pass: 980
KEY: 000
```

`/.../,/.../` is used to name the start and end markers which are printed.

However, the output requirements complicate the program a bit:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=": *";OFS=":" }           # set appropriate delimiters
/^end:/ { print "{";f=1 }            # print at start marker and raise flag
f { print "\"" $1"\"","\"" $2"\"" }  # when flag up, print
/^KEY:/ { print "}";f="" }           # at end-marker, print end marker and flag down
' file
{
"end":"123.12.12.12"
"text_pass":"980"
"KEY":"000"
}
```

If you want to use and empty line as end marker, use `/^$/ && f` instead of `/^KEY:/`.

Comment: a new line instead of Key makes more sense as its possible that the sequence changes.

Comment: I get no such file or directory if I use the above edit

Comment: Well, then remove the `file` from the end of the command and feed input to it thru a pipe, just like in your own example above: `cf env space | awk ...`.